# Where in local TEXMF tree should I put a file that I regularly `\input`

Tags: input, texmf

I have a chunk of TeX code, I use to setup some styles for drawing block diagrams in Tikz.

Since i draw a fair few block diagrams, I thought I would stop copy-pasting it around and put it in a separate file.
And then just `\input` it in each file that has a block diagram.

This has clean up my code a fair bit.

What I would is to put it somewhere in my TeXMF tree, so that I don't need to give a path to it each time.
But where do I put it?

The file in question looks like:

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%...
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{
    input/.style={
        circle,
        draw,
        Blue,
        minimum width = 2
    },
    %...
    labe/.style={
        fill=white,
        fill opacity=0.6,
        text opacity=1,
        font={\footnotesize\itshape}    
    }
}
```

I am using MikTeX (mostly), but I am also interested in answers that cover TeXLive.

Comment: Which TeX distribution? I would use `$(kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/tikz-oxinabox/` or similar. (TeX Live, bash-type shell)

Comment: If not on Windows, what about: `mkdir -vp "$(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/oxinaboxinputs"`? The normal place for personal things is in `TEXMFHOME`, which you can learn via `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME`.  Then you make the subdirectories `tex`, `latex`, and `oxinaboxinputs`, and you put your stuff there.

Comment: @jon You need `mkdir -p`.

Comment: @cfr -- good catch.

Comment: @cfr I use MikTeX on my main computer and TeXLive on several others (but I've never managed to get the TEXMFHOME to work the way I want with version controlled trees with TeXLive)

Comment: I think the answer I am looking for is `/tex/latex/tikz-oxinabox/`
@cfr do you want o make that an answer?

Comment: That is not the answer: the key is that you need to first learn what `TEXMFHOME` is, then create the appropriate directory structure 'below' that. For me (on GNU/Linux) `TEXMFHOME` is `~/texmf`; so I'd be creating `~/texmf/tex/latex/joninputs` and putting my things there.

Comment: Consider the possibility of writing it as a `*.sty` file, along with internal identifier as a package. Then when you update your local or home texmf tree, it will be found. Instead of `\input{}` you would `\usepackage{}`. However, do not attempt to put it in the texmf system tree; not only is that bad practice, but I believe that MikTeX refuses to recognize strange packages there. If your file is something other than TeX code (say, an image) then I do not know what works.

Comment: @jon I know what TEXMFHOME is. It is the place I keep things that are not system packages, and on Miktex I set its location in the settings, and on TEXLIVE i do it with `tlmgr`. I'm just not sure on the appropriate director structure with-in it.
(I know that BST files need to go in `/bib/bst/X/` and BIBtext databases `bib/bst/X/`. But I don't know where random chunks of latex go. I know document classes, and maybe some other things go in `tex\latex/X`, but idk what)

Comment: Well, if you know what `TEXMFHOME` is I'm not sure why you'd write that @cfr's answer was `/tex/latex/...` (which no one reading this should use!) unless it was a typo. The point is that you should put this in `$TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/` and normally it makes sense to create a directory below `latex` as has been suggested. What does this means for MikTeX? I have no idea. How it works for TeX Live on Windows? Not sure, but I'd assume you still need to mimic the TEXMF structure for your 'home' folder.

Comment: `/tex/latex/...` as relative to the TEXMFHOME root (not relative to the filesystem root) I guess my question really comes down to _"What is the TEXMF structure for your 'home' folder?"_, and _"where to files to be `\input` go within it?"_.

Comment: You are quite free where you put such files and how you name the folders as long as you use a subfolder of tex. tex/latex/oxi, tex/generic/oxi (if you also want them to use with other formats) are sensible choices. Pay attention that  you don't use a file name that is used by some other package.

Comment: @Oxinabox `/` at the start means this is an absolute path starting from the root of the file system. `/tex/latex` is therefore wrong and cannot be a relative pathname. `tex/latex` is relative to some other place, which may be what you wanted to say.

Comment: I figured it was apparent, since the question title says "Where **in** local TEXMF tree...", in anycase, this is just a question of pragmatics. Clearly i got the pragmatics of the situation wrong, since it was **not** apparent what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a LocalTeXMF directory, if you do not have already one, via `MiKTeX Settings`, `Roots` tab.

This loacl root must have the same structure as the main root. Your  input files should go, as you suggest in `LocalTeXMF/tex/latex/tikz-oxinabox`. If there's a documentation, it should go to 
 `LocalTeXMF/doc/latex/tikz-oxinabox`.

As a last step, refresh the FNDB with MiKTeX Settings, `General` tab.
[image]

Comment: Why `LocalTeXMF/tex/latex/` and not `LocalTeXMF/tex/generic/` ?
( I suspect i know the answer, it is because things in /generic/ should work in ConTeXt and ordinary TeX and anywhere else?)

Comment: I hesitated, and finally chose `/latex/` because it was about TikZ, but `/generic` would be fine too.

Comment: Shall I ask another question about the differnence between `/latex` and `/generic` ?

Comment: `generic/` is for macros that can be used with all flavours of TeX (a typical example is `insbox`,  a set of plain TeX macros for inserting any kind of box in a paragraph, somewhat like `wrapfigure`, which is useful with LaTeX in situations where wrapfigure does not work).